Dynamic filter options using shorter URLs
What if we want to have GET requests send from a Frontend App to a REST API where the parameters can be huge?
The scenario is an endpoint that can receive a huge amount of filters, by huge is over 7k characters. To be more precise think about giving the option for the user to set filters to a Customer name (over 1000 options), city (worldwide), and then a couple dozen more filters which options can range from 5 to 100 options to select.
So, imagine that the URL would become something like:
www.host.com/something/some-module?filter1=huge-amount-of-characters&filter2=another-huge-amount-of-characters&filter3&filter4......&filter12=think-this-is-over-5-lines-on-ultra-wide-resolution-font-size-12
As a result, we had some problems where our APIs, one running Quarkus and the other FastAPI, refused to process the request because of size of the URL. We also had issues on the browser side running our Angular app, where the filters (UI) would be set based on the query params of the URL. We tweaked the configs on the apps and raised the limit, but I would like to have something that did not require that approach.
I did some initial testing:

with SHA, but it is not lossless, and by my understanding it could turn out to lose part of the filters when decoding.
with gzip and Base64, but I am not sure FE frameworks can handle the gzip part for enconding URLs params before passing those to Base64. On the BE side, it kinda worked, but again, sounds too much.
I thought about url-rewriting, seems that it could help, but I could not get my head around it to make work on the FE side, since those url params are also needed to set the state of the filters on the UI and this pattern seems to be server side only.

And again, there is always the possibility of just using POST instead of GET, but we got some noise on that because "it is not the REST right way".
While I do understand that the GET verb is the correct one to be used for my requests that just returns values based on query filters, I also understand that I have a requirement that does not fit in well with browsers and backend frameworks for that verb.
So the question here is, do any of you know of a pattern, or maybe a lib that would help handling this scenario, or should I just go with POST since I can pass all these parameters in the body of the request instead. Do take note that those filters will be dynamic, the filters and their respective amount may increase or decrease and both FE and BE needs to be able to cope with that.

Use POST or QUERY. QUERY is very new, but will work in most places as long as your server supports it. Putting this much data in the URL is not a good idea.
If you want the response of query to be cacheable by standard browsers you can also build an endpoint with POST to initially 'submit' the request, and as a second step do a GET request on some 'result resource' that gets created by the first POST with a short url.
Sidenote: sha is a hash function and not reversable. It's not magic compression or encryption.

considering the maximum recommended URL length is <2000 characters for cross browser compatibility, you probably need to rethink your api design.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/8564731
secondly, filtering that much of your data through the api is typically not recommended. Returning a paginated list and a few key attributes to narrow the results is a better recommendation. There are multiple ways to design pagination.
If you really want to support some sort of advanced query mechanism, try OData or you can even try a GraphQL service rather than a rest service.
If all else fails, filter on the UI
